# LazyImage Loading in Auth0 SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, auth0

I'm a brand new developer to swift, and am trying to understand how to load an image into the Auth0 SDK.

The [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/v2/customization) describes this:

```
        return Lock
            .classic()
            .withStyle {
                $0.logo = LazyImage(name: "myimagename")
```

However, I'm not sure where to put the image referenced in myimagename?

going into the LazyImage struct, it describes:

````
 Creates a LazyImage with a name and an optional Bundle.
 For images outside Lock's bundle you should specify the Bundle like

 ```
 let image = LazyImage(name: "image_name")
 ```
````

So do I somehow add this image to Assets, or in a .plist file or just put a JPG in a folder somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the image to the assets folder `Images.xcassets` it should be able to find it! Let me know if it works.